# How to add anchor in a more complex situation?

Tags: php, anchor

The final goal is it to find a certain entry among many others. To do so, the user can either look trough a treeview or use a search function (with several filters).
Both is implemented in one site; when ste it opened, the user is presented two buttons for either choice. A click ony, say, the search button makes the search function visible.

Now, after selecting filters, the user presses another button which triggers the search and presents the results. Unfortunately, this makes the view go back to the top - I'd like it rather to stay at the now presented search results.

To do that, I want to use an anchor.

Both form and procedure are in the same php file and interact like this:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['btn-filterSort'])){
<do your search stuff and present results>
}
?>

<form id="filtersort" method="post">    
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="btn-filterSort">Search</button>
</form>
```

If i now add something like

```
header("Location: #searchanchor");
```

it does add this to my URL, but the search function is not displayed anymore, but only the two initial two buttons where the user can choose between treeview and searching.

How can I let the script do what it was doing before and simply adding this anchor to the URL?

Thanks, Julian

Comment: When you use `header` you are overwriting the data passed in. Why not use PHP to output some Javascript to scroll to the anchor?

Comment: You could search using AJAX instead of reloading the page at all, thereby maintaining the state.  If I understand the problem correctly.  Bit hard to follow.

Comment: Thanks, will try which one works better for me!